# How to print math multiplication table returning String value in 2x2 and 3x3 matrix using nested loops in Java

Tags: java, string, junit, formatting, nested-loops

I'm trying to get the method that would return the following String for an integer parameter of 2:

Output:

[image]

Same for parameter of 3

[image]

The code which I got so far is below:

```
public String simpleMultiplicationTable(int num) {
    for(int i = 1 ;i<=num;i++) {
        for(int j=1;j<=num;j++) {
            System.out.format("%4d",i*j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return String.valueOf(num);      
}
```

Comment: Please use formatted text in the question rather than pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing each value, append it to a `StringBuilder` and return the same at the end.

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(simpleMultiplicationTable(2));
        System.out.println(simpleMultiplicationTable(3));
    }

    public static String simpleMultiplicationTable(int num) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
                sb.append(i * j);
                if (j < num) {
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
            }
            if (i < num) {
                sb.append("\n");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2
2 4
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

## Using `String` instead of `StringBuilder`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(simpleMultiplicationTable(2));
        System.out.println(simpleMultiplicationTable(3));
    }

    public static String simpleMultiplicationTable(int num) {
        String table = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
                table += j < num ? i * j + " " : i * j;
            }
            if (i < num) {
                table = table + "\n";
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

## JUnit Tests

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class TestMethods {

    @Test
    public void testSimpleMultiplicationTable() {
        Table table = new Table();
        String result = table.simpleMultiplicationTable(2);
        if (result.contains(" \n")) {
            fail("Your output table has one or more extra spaces before the newline character. You can use the trim() function to remove additional spaces");
        }
        assertEquals("1 2\n2 4", result);

        result = table.simpleMultiplicationTable(1);
        if (result.contains(" \n")) {
            fail("Your output table has one or more extra spaces before the newline character. You can use the trim() function to remove additional spaces");
        }
        assertEquals("1", result);
    }
}

class Table {

    public String simpleMultiplicationTable(int num) {
        String table = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
                table += j < num ? i * j + " " : i * j;
            }
            if (i < num) {
                table = table + "\n";
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. It's giving an error:

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :   1

Comment: This is my test class:

 @Test
    public void testSimpleMultiplicationTable() {
        String result = assignmentOnePartTwo.simpleMultiplicationTable(2);
        if (result.contains(" \n")) {
            fail("Your output table has one or more extra spaces before the newline character. You can use the trim() function to remove additional spaces");
        }
        assertEquals("1 2 \n2 4", result);
    }

Comment: @user13060550  - I've updated the answer. Now, it passes your test case. Let me know in case of any further issue/doubt.

Comment: Is it possible without public static void main(String[] args)?

Comment: I've updated the answer to adapt to your JUnit test cases. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.